# Eclipse android can't make views bigger

Tags: android, eclipse, view

If i try to make the thing u see in the screenshot it just falls back to original size. I can't change sizes of any view Objects. Anybody knows a fix?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRyxe.jpg

Comment: can you post your XML file containing this view ?

Comment: It's not about the view it's more generall i can't change the size on 2 computes on any project. It has probably something to do with the default eclipse settings

Comment: i cant tell you what wrong just from the image, i'm not a wizard

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse (as you're using the designer), you can set the `Width` and `Height` of a View, within the **Layout Parameters** section of the **Properties** pane. This can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or `fill_parent`.

You can also do this within the XML markup of the activity you're editing. Click the **.xml** tab at the bottom of your designer, and you'll see all of the XML that makes up your activity. Once in there, find the problematic view and add:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

**Edit**
Also, when inside of a `RelativeLayout`, it's possible that Eclipse will add default padding values, so regardless of what you set, your View's wont reach the parent layout's edge, until you remove them. Just FYI!